# Gazebo and Real world Contact Sensors

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to simulate a Service robot which features bumpers and also I want to build a real one.
Now the question is, what topics to use?
The Bumper plugin for Gazebo outputs a lot of information on the contact, but I only want to know if it is pressed or not. Also when it is in the Gazebo package, I guess it should be used  for simulation only, right?

What topic shall I use for real sensors?

Bool?

And how to interface Gazebo?
Do I have to write my own node to get the pressed state from the topic?
Or is there somehing ready to use?

How do I interface this to already available ROS planing systems?
Is there a common way to do this?
Or do I have to add Obstacles to the costmap myself somehow, when a bumper is being pressed?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204146/gazebo-and-real-world-contact-sensors./) by [LucianTM](https://answers.ros.org/users/21714/luciantm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2015-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe there are proper standards for this.

A good example might be the turtlbot's base, i.e. Kobuki.
There is a bumper message and to get it into move_base, these are converted to point clouds:
http://wiki.ros.org/kobuki_bumper2pc?distro=indigo

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LucianTM](https://answers.ros.org/users/21714/luciantm/) on 2015-03-09**:
Hmm, think so too...